# Compare columns of numbers and locate duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with 9000 rows and it has 4 columns of numbers. I need to find out if any number in any column is duplicated anywhere else in any column or the same column

So let's say I have this

```
203511    203509    203506    203507
203512    203510    203505    203508
203513    203511    203512    203520
203514    203512    203507    203521
```

In the example the numbers 203512 and 203507 would be a duplicates and would need to be identified somehow. They will probably not be within a row of each other either.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Per your comments under my answer, can you please give a more descriptive summary of what you need done? Even if it's 100 columns, the conditional formatting would point out duplicates.  When you say "I need to find out if any number in any column is duplicated...", the conditional formatting will do this in no time.  Please give more detail.

Comment: Provided a solution with formulas, however VBA will certainly be more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would Conditional Formatting work?  A really quick way is to select your entire range, go to Conditional Formatting --> Highlight Cell Rules --> Duplicates.  Then you can set how to show the duplicates.

Then, as you delete 2 of the 3 duplicates, the coloring will automatically go away when there's just one entry left (as seen below):

[image]

There are other options too, from a `countif` formula that shows you how many times a number is repeated.  And of course we can get more complex with VBA if necessary.  What's your overall goal in identifying the duplicates? Once identified, what do you plan on doing?

edit: If downvoting, please explain why. I answered the question as presented in the OP, no?

> In the example the numbers 203512 and 203507 would be a duplicates and would need to be identified somehow. They will probably not be within a row of each other either.

The above does exactly that.

Comment: I know it sounds strange but I need to first determine if there are any. Then the work is to decide what to do with them if there are any. This is a multi part project. This is step one. What I forgot to add was that there are dozens of other columns on both sides of these columns if that makes any difference

Comment: I just got thrown a curveball. It turns out that there is another column that needs to be added to the list of numbers being searched. So now in addition to the original 4 columns, each column has to also include Col C as part of its comparison. There are days when I really do not like my job :)

Comment: @rrumaner - this will work on 1 column or 100 columns.  You can even just select columns A:AZ and do the above steps and get the highlighted duplicates.  Why isn't that okay? What do you actually want to do with the duplicates??  If there are no duplicates, then there'll be no highlighting. I can't think of a quicker way to find duplicates for dozens of columns (even a formula to tell you would take more time, as you have to type it in, etc.).

Comment: I need to compare the 4 columns in conjunction to a another column that contains part numbers (ex. ABCD123456...ZYXW987654). There can be many of the same part numbers but if a part number has a duplicate in one of the 4 columns, I need to identify them. I sorted on the parts column (Col C) and then did the Cond. Formatting and that got me much closer to what I need. Now I can scroll down the columns looking for the color bars and determine if they are associated with the same parts or not.

Comment: @rrumaner - can you edit your OP to include this information, so I (and others) can see it in the question? I'll take a look and see what I can do.  How do you know which duplicates to delete? We can work on a more robust answer if you give us an overview of your problem/wishes as well.

Comment: What you have given me so far has gotten me to point where I can get the information I need. I just kept playing around with the various sorting and formatting.

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes sample data is located at `B3:E7` *(adjust ranges in formulas as required)*

It uses four working columns to identify duplicates for each field located at `G3:J7`. Enter this formula in `G4` and copy till last record then to columns `H`, `I` and `J`.

```
=IF( EXACT( B4, "" ), "",
IF( SUM(
COUNTIF( $B$4:$B$7,B4 ),
COUNTIF( $C$4:$C$7,B4 ),
COUNTIF( $D$4:$D$7,B4 ),
COUNTIF( $E$4:$E$7,B4 ) ) = 1, "", B4 ) )
```

Unique list of duplicated items located at `L3:L10`. Enter this `FormulaArray` in `L4` then copy till last record

*(Enter the* `FormulaArray` *pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously, you shall see `{` `}` around the formula if entered correctly)*

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( $G$4:$G$7, MATCH( 0, COUNTIF( L$3:L4, $G$4:$G$7 ), 0 ) * 1 ),
IFERROR( INDEX( $H$4:$H$7, MATCH( 0, COUNTIF( L$3:L4, $H$4:$H$7 ), 0 ) * 1 ),
IFERROR( INDEX( $I$4:$I$7, MATCH( 0, COUNTIF( L$3:L4, $I$4:$I$7 ), 0 ) * 1 ),
IFERROR( INDEX( $J$4:$J$7, MATCH( 0, COUNTIF( L$3:L4, $J$4:$J$7 ), 0 ) * 1 ), "" ) ) ) )
```

[image]

Comment: At the time of this answer  the question is still showing only four columns to be compared. Nevertheless the solution can be update to care for additional columns as the formula for duplicates is common to all columns.

Comment: Interesting idea. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to do this in VB... so I will just explain an efficientish alg...

1. step 1 sort each column
2. iterate col 1, use binary search to see if it is in col 2,3, or 4.
3. iterate col 2 against 3, 4
4. iterate col 3 against col 4

you can probably skip sorting, an binary searching ... because you only have 9000 elements... it shouldn't take long to run